# Is there a way to override instance variable lookup in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Say if I want to return something else if a variable isn't initialized instead of `nil`.  Is this possible? I'd like to only overload it per class, not globally.

(The reason for this is mainly to play with crazy tricks).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Does Ruby have a method_missing equivalent for undefined instance variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651213/does-ruby-have-a-method-missing-equivalent-for-undefined-instance-variables)

Comment: I don't have any plans to use this in production

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you could use `#instance_variable_defined?` and `#instance_variable_get`. For instance:

```
class Thing
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    ivar_name = "@#{method}".intern

    if instance_variable_defined? ivar_name
      instance_variable_get ivar_name
    else
      super method, *args, &block
    end
  end
end
```

would automatically define instance variable readers for any set instance variables, or:

```
class Thing
  IVARS = [:@first, :@second]

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    ivar_name = "@#{method}".intern

    if IVARS.include? ivar_name
      if instance_variable_defined? ivar_name
        instance_variable_get ivar_name
      else
        "your default"
      end
    else
      super method, *args, &block
    end
  end
end
```

would define readers for any if the instance variables named in the `IVARS` constant, defaulting to the default value. I'm sure you can see how you could change that to be a hash mapping instance variable names to their default values or whatever.

Or you could simply use `instance_variable_get` to provide a default value if you don't need any more flexibility than this:

```
thing = Thing.new
thing.instance_variable_get :@ivar_name, "your default"
```

although this would not define reader methods - you would have to access via `instance_variable_get` each time.

Comment: The behavior I am seeing is that method_missing is not being called when I try to access an attribute that is undefined, it just directly evaluates as Nil without being intercepted.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you could write a wrapper method

```
def something
  @var || "your default"
end
```

Comment: If this is possible I'd like this to happen automatically for any instance variable lookup (just lookup, assignment is unimportant)

Comment: and it has to be using @ not a setter